# Social network plugins for Wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, customization

I would like to make my blog fully integrated with social networks. This mean:
* Login via facebook / twitter

- Share to facebook / twitter
- Include open graph data in the page
- any other suggestions

I've tried:

- Twit Connect but if you enable showing of tweet button under posts, it is included under pages too.
- ShareThis - it has option to show only under posts, but it stopped working after I've installed Simple OpenGraph.
- Simple OpenGraph - I'm happy with this one.

*So, I think a canonical answer for this would be helpfull for the community and I'll be happy to give bounty for such.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing any one-shop-for-all plugin type, but for Facebook, you can try the [Simple Facebook Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/) by Otto.

This plugin let you enable the single features that you require for your blog, including registering via FB, login via FB, post to your wall... OpenGraph... etc.

Comment: Thanks. I've didn't noticed it has OpenGraph data. I'll check if it plays nice with Simple Twitter Connect

Comment: Try and let me know!

Answer (score 0):

We (Crowd Favorite and MailChimp) created a plugin called "[Social](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social/)" which will allow you to:

- broadcast newly published posts to Twitter accounts and Facebook profiles/pages
- have visitors leave comments as their Facebook/Twitter identities
- pull in Twitter/Facebook reactions to your post (by searching for mentions of the post URL, looking for retweets and replies to the broadcasted tweet, etc.)
- and much more...

Answer (score -1):

I belong to [LoginRadius](http://www.loginradius.com) and we offer 'Social login for WordPress' plugin that enables full integration with popular social networks such as Facebook, Twitter, Googel and 15 more. Though, it doesn't include 'Open Graph' etc.

You can download and try it [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/loginradius-for-wordpress/).